# Crash when trying to apply drag drop reorder to a ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to apply drag drop to a dynamically created collection of buttons on a ItemsControl. I get an error:

Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel.

I am not sure how I can fix this.

My xaml:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" IsTabStop="False" Name="icsp"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContentButtons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="sp" AllowDrop="True" Background="SkyBlue" 
                        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="sp_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
                        PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="sp_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" 
                        PreviewMouseMove="sp_PreviewMouseMove"
                        DragEnter="sp_DragEnter" Drop="sp_Drop"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

My code behind:

```
  public partial class Admin : UserControl
    {
        public Admin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private bool _isDown;
        private bool _isDragging;
        private Point _startPoint;
        private UIElement _realDragSource;
        private UIElement _dummyDragSource = new UIElement();

        private void sp_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var sp = FindChild<StackPanel>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "sp");
            if (e.Source == sp)
            {
            }
            else
            {              
                _isDown = true;                             
                _startPoint = e.GetPosition(sp);                       
            }
        }

        private void sp_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _isDown = false;
            _isDragging = false;
            _realDragSource.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        private void sp_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {          
            if (_isDown)
            {
                var sp = FindChild<StackPanel>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "sp");
                if ((_isDragging == false) &&
                    ((Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(sp).X - _startPoint.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance) ||
                     (Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(sp).Y - _startPoint.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)))
                {
                    _isDragging = true;
                    _realDragSource = e.Source as UIElement;
                    _realDragSource.CaptureMouse();
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(_dummyDragSource, new DataObject("UIElement", e.Source, true),
                        DragDropEffects.Move);
                }
            }
        }

        private void sp_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("UIElement"))
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;               
            }
        }

        private void sp_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("UIElement"))
            {
                var sp = FindChild<StackPanel>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "sp");
                UIElement droptarget = e.Source as UIElement;
                int droptargetIndex =-1, i =0;
                foreach (UIElement element in sp.Children)
                {
                    if (element.Equals(droptarget))
                    {
                        droptargetIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (droptargetIndex != -1)
                {
                    sp.Children.Remove(_realDragSource);
                    sp.Children.Insert(droptargetIndex, _realDragSource);
                }

                _isDown = false;
                _isDragging = false;
                _realDragSource.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            }
        }
```

Find child is a method used to search the visual tree and grab the panel named sp. It works and returns the control. When I apply this code to a stack panel with buttons created in xaml everything works. It is just when I try to use it in an ItemsControl that it blows up.

Comment: When you debug it, which part of the code is giving you error? Remember that the number of instances of your StackPanel is equal to the number of the Items in your ItemsControl. So which of these StackPanel (if more than one) is to be returned when you use FindChild()?

Comment: The exception is quite clear: your code is attempting to modify the `StackPanel` children directly, when that is **not allowed**. If you want to change the order of the items, you need to change the order in the original items collection, i.e. in the `ContentButtons` that is bound to the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property. How best to do that depends on the rest of the code, which you haven't provided. Please see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: The item source is bound to a collection on the view model. I had assumed that it would be updated when the collection was modified. I will look at how I can modify the collection on the view model. Thank you for your pointers.

Comment: This error was happening on the drop method in my code.

Comment: Peter Duniho, you pointed me in the right direction. If you propose that as an answer I would gladly accept it as an answer.